# MATLAB create title over one column of subplot

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure

So I have a 3x3 array of subplots.  I know how to get a title on each one of them, and I know how to get a "super title" using the suptitle function over the whole thing, but I can't figure out how to get titles to only show up over each column.  I also want to do a similar thing with the rows.  Think hip, knee, ankle across the top, then angular velocity, torque, and power down the left side.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `text` to label the columns and rows.

```
subplot(2,2,1)
title('a')
h1 = text(-0.25, 0.5,'row 1');
set(h1, 'rotation', 90)
text(0.35,1.2,'column 1');

subplot(2,2,2)
title('b')
text(0.35,1.2,'column 2');
subplot(2,2,3)

title('c')
h = text(-0.25, 0.5, 'row 2');
set(h, 'rotation', 90)
subplot(2,2,4)
title('d')
```

The position of text will have to be adjusted based on the x and y range of your plots.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I had found the text function but was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Why not just use `title` but only put it on the graphs in the top row? Similarly, only use the yaxis label on the graphs on the left hand column?

Comment: That works if you don't want titles  and y-labels on each subplot in addition to column and row labels.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments to the other answer, you can do this using titles and y-labels in individual subplots.

Use `title` on the top row of plots to produce column labels.
For row labels, take advantage of the (possibly undocumented?) feature that allows you to have multi-row labels, thus:

`ylabel({'Row label' 'Actual y-label'});`

It's a nasty kludge, and it's a PITA if your subplots are generated within a loop, but until/unless Mathworks give us a proper to way to do this it's the best that I know of.